# Why Base64 ends with a newline? (\n)

Tags: export, string-manipulation, conversion

Why everything converted to Base64 has a newline at the end? It isn't one of base characters, is it?

```
Style[
 b64 = ExportString["some pig", "Base64"],
 ShowStringCharacters -> True
 ]
```

> ```
> "c29tZSBwaWc=\n"
> ```

Moreover, it seems that it doesn't matter if you drop it or not:

```
ImportString[#, "Base64"] & /@ {b64, StringDrop[b64, -1]}
```

> ```
> {"some pig", "some pig"}
> ```

But it may matter in general.

Related [chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25682914#25682914).

Using [SO js example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript). Try in console

> > btoa("some pig")
>
> < "c29tZSBwaWc="

Comment: `Style[b64 = ExportString["some pig", "UUE"], 
 ShowStringCharacters -> True]` also does add some extra `\n`.

Comment: Maybe it's an [Encoding Formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/CompressionAndArchiveFormats.html) thing. Did you check the official Base64 standard recommendations?

Comment: This [silly image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwb47.png) shows an annoyance that maybe was intended to be avoided, but it is probably irrelevant :P.

Comment: From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#MIME): "most implementations use a CR/LF [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) pair to delimit encoded lines"

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom seems related, but is it explaining a newline after short string?

Comment: I think that short string is to be interpreted as the last encoded line.  It may be convenient to be able to assume that all lines are delimited by newlines.

Comment: ``Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]; Style[
 b64 = Base64String[ToCharacterCode["some pig"]], 
 ShowStringCharacters -> True]`` doesn't have a `\n` at the end, but also no padding `=` and therefore `ImportString[b64, "Base64"]` just returns `"some p"`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I suppose it is the case, but as usual I feel like the documentation could be better. Please consider posting the answer.

Answer (score 9):

It won't happen only at the end of the encoding but rather every 76 characters resulting from the encoding.

For many old programs that couldn't handle reading long lines, introducing a newline character was introduced every certain number of characters. In computer science argot this is called text wrapping. I guess that the number 76 of characters comes from the *good practice* of having code lines of at most 80 characters and having 2 per side as margin (although not sure why exactly two). This choose of 76 characters (or columns) comes from the standards in [RFC2045](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt) (page 19 paragraph 5) and is also a standard in the Linux command [base64](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/base64-invocation.html).

Nevertheless, there should be an option to change this default of 76 characters and I couldn't find it anywhere.

[image: Base 64 encoding]

Comment: So it doesn't seem that 76 characters wide line is related to the new line at the end of base64 string.

Comment: Ah, you meant just at the end? Well, I'd guess that it's meant to keep the maximum of 76 even when you concatenate two encodings.

Comment: That could be a valid reason but then I suppose this end new line should be there for every ExportString type.

Comment: That would be problematic with other standards, for instance CSV. Consider the following:
`ExportString[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, "CSV"]`
against
`ExportString[{a, b,c, d}, "CSV"]`

Comment: And probably most importantly, how `a,b\nc,d` is imported in comparison to `a,b,c,d` in CSV as well.

Comment: I think it's not a margin of 2 characters at each side but rather 4 at the beginning and none at the end. This is so that you can fit your line-numbered Fortran code onto a punched card. I find this standard very sensible and useful because it helps to remind us of the arbitrary technical limitations of equipment that ceased to be used 40 years ago.

Comment: for the record , punch cards were long gone by the time base64 was developed. It was about 7bit clean transport via plain text email.